# Excel - how to get auto number in levelling columns?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, excel-2016, autonumber

I want to count on the data in same columns and restart the count if there have new data in upper level (say previous column), see my picture.

[image]

I use the formula of counta, but the numbering is incorrect (say row 8 in example)

`=COUNTA(D$3:D8)&COUNTA(E$3:E8)&COUNTA(F$3:F8)&COUNTA(G$3:G8)&COUNTA(H$3:H8)&COUNTA(I$3:I8)`

Is it possible to solve by vba?

Answer (score 0):

I assume *no Excel version constraints as per the tags in the question*. You can try the following formula in `B2`. The number of levels is variable so you can have more than `6`.

```
=LET(x, N(C2:H10<>""), seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)), levels, COLUMNS(x),
 CNTS, LAMBDA(i, LET(A, IF(i=1, N(seq<0),INDEX(x,,i-1)), B, INDEX(x,,i),
   SCAN(0, seq, LAMBDA(ac,s, IF(INDEX(A,s)>0,0,ac) + INDEX(B,s))))),
 REDUCE(CNTS(1), SEQUENCE(levels-1,,2), LAMBDA(ac,z, ac & CNTS(z))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

It is an array formula, so it spills the entire result. The name `x`, generates `1`'s from the grid: `C2:H10` if the value is not empty, otherwise `0`'s. It will be our main input for the calculation. The **main idea** is to build a cumulative calculation with "*memory*", i.e. we need to take into consideration the information from the previous column.

In order to build this cumulative calculation with "*memory*" we use a user `LAMBDA` function `CNTS`, to calculate the counts for a given column (`i`). The `CNTS` takes into account the previous column (`i-1`) to reset the accumulator (`ac`). We use `SCAN` to do the cumulative sum and reset the accumulator (`ac`) if the row of the previous corresponding column is positive, by doing this way we can start the counter again.

The rest is just to do a recursive concatenation via `REDUCE` for all the levels.

**Notes**:

1. We could have the case of the first column (no previous information) as a simpler `SCAN` call, but it can be generalized to consider all cases within the same `CNTS` function. Therefore we have an `IF` condition for the case the column is `1`, so we create on the fly an artificial previous column via `N(seq <0)` which is a constant column with zero values.
2. `levels` must be greater than `1`, which is a reasonable assumption. If you want to consider `levels=1` for the sake of a more generic formula, then you can add an `IF` condition before `REDUCE`, because we don't need a recursion for that, for example, `IF(level=1, CNTS(1), REDUCE(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My excel version is 2016, the cell value return 0. It seems not working ...

Comment: @winw for this version, I don't have a solution, it is too old, and you don't have `SEQUENCE` available, and none of the array functions. It will be hard and a very large formula probably, maybe others can help. Sorry

Comment: no worries, thank you for your contribution. Looking for a simple solution for numbering.

Comment: @winw thanks, the way to say thank you is by upvoting the answer, :-)